# MVC Windows Authentication 401 on authorised pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, model-view-controller

I have an MVC5 website whereby I want anyone to be able to view the site apart from a restricted Admin area. I have created a filter to check the users AD group which I've applied to the admin controllers and this works absolutely fine.

The issues is for people viewing the main site, if its idle for a while they get an unauthorised response upon navigating to a page. Once they refresh its fine and allows them back into the page.

Web.Config has the following in

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

If I remove this then problem goes away but admin controllers don't work as there is no windows user found in my custom filter.

The custom filter just checks for a AD group:

```
 var groupList = GetGroupList();

        if (base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(groupList))
                return true;

            var groups = groupList.Split(',').ToList();

            var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "MYDOMAIN");

            var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(
                context,
                IdentityType.SamAccountName,
                httpContext.User.Identity.Name);

            if (userPrincipal == null)
                return false;

            try
            {
                foreach (var group in groups)
                    if (userPrincipal.IsMemberOf(context,
                         IdentityType.Name,
                         group))
                        return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to redirect the user on some Error page on unauthorised access.
  You can do this by adding this in web config . (AccessDenied.aspx page is where you have written a message for Un Authorised user access)

```
      <customErrors defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.aspx" mode="On"> 
     <error statusCode="401" redirect="AccessDenied.aspx" />       
   </customErrors>
```

OR You can do this in Global.asax file

```
     protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, 
                                                EventArgs e)
        {
      if (!Request.IsAuthenticated) Response.Redirect(
                                        "AccessDenied.aspx"); 
     }
```

Comment: For some reason though I'm getting a redirect to the access denied page even though the controller has no [Authorize] attribute, anyone should be able to view the page.

Answer (score 0):

In my recent experience, working with AD from an IIS box, I am using an identical filter to filter by AD group. And although my filter is identical, I noticed `httpContext.User.Identity.Name` doesn't return the user like in a 'normal' anonymous website in a controller.

And to make it automagically authorize by AD user sans login screen, I had to disable anonymous auth, enable windows auth, set `<identity impersonate="true" />` and use:

```
 UserPrincipal adUser = null;
        using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
        {
            var userContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
            PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AllowedDomain"], null,
                ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer);
            adUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, userContext.Name);
        }
// and work with 'adUser' from here on in my controllers...
```

My app is just going into production internally now but I am not experiencing your psuedo 'timeout' issues. Do you have any extraneous forms auth tags lingering in your web.config?

I also had to set `<sessionState mode="InProc" />` in my web.config as well.